# Placing an image into a div tag in a timeline box

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place an image in the timeline box.

Full code is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xmbohx/62hwrf9n/6/)

Adding this code :

```
<div class="container left-container">
        <img src="images/logo1.png" />
        <div class="text-box">
          <h2>Alfabet Inc</h2>
          <small>2018-2019</small>
          <p>
            Another writing challenge can be to take the individual sentences in
            You also won't know exactly how many sentences will appear in the
            random paragraph.
          </p>
<img src="https://www.mydomaine.com/thmb/qfc13qpHnxMkqp8Ja-XwYjC1JQ8=/750x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc():format(webp)/SuCasaDesign-Modern-9335be77ca0446c7883c5cf8d974e47c.jpg">

         
          <span class="left-container-arrow"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
```

and CSS :

```
.text-box img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 1%;
    vertical-align: middle; 
}
```

The image is shown but not as expected. I would like to have a full-responsive image shown inside the "text-box"

Please advise.

Comment: The image is being positioned according to your `.container img { }` rule. Your browser's Developer Tools is a very helpful resource.

Comment: Could you describe a bit more how the image should look? Is it to be a circle with the text flowing round it, or is it to be after the text?

Comment: Hi @AHaworth I would need it square [Pic](https://tinypic.host/image/C0XUB)

Comment: And is it to be before or after the text?

Comment: I would need it both before and after

Comment: Is it really to appear twice?

Comment: Once only, but. it can be place after the <p>text</p> of before it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can see this:

[Timeline with picture](https://codepen.io/oggygo/pen/VwVNeRx)

```
<div class="timeline">
      <!--div class="container"-->
      <div class="container left">        
        <div class="content">
          <h2>Mosque</h2>
          <img src="image.jpg" alt="" />
          <p>
            sometext
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!---/container-->
```